# SAML certificate authentication vs login

Tags: yii2, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

I have a working implementation of SAML (OneLogin) within an enterprise architecture.

When a guest user arrives at my application they are redirected to the company login where they enter their username / password. After that the user identity is passed back to my application and we log them in.

However, I notice that in other applications within the company I do not have to login at all. Somehow the website "knows who I am" and seems to authenticate me automatically. I presume there is some form of certificate on my pc / browser which the other applications are passing to the SAML??

Can somebody tell me the technical term or process? Is there a process whereby I simply pull the certificate from the browser or PC and pass it to the SAML? I would like my users to be able to auto-login without entering their credentials.

Thanks

Comment: Acronyms to know about: **SSO** (single Sign-On) and **ISP** (Identity Service Provider). In the legacy world of Windows on-prem, the ISP is Microsoft Active Directory, with Kerberos for authentication _(authn)_ based on login/pwd; and LDAP for authorization _(authz)_ with a mix of (a) policies & (b) access rules mapped on user groups. Optionally you can judge passwords are not safe enough and opt for user certificates inside a smartcard, USB dongle, whatever.

Comment: And your on-prem web apps may benefit from SSO, either via SPNego _(a challenge/response using your local Kerberos token)_ or SAML _(an HTTP redirection to your ISP, which may challenge your identity again, then redirect back with an ID token)_.

Comment: In the wonderful world of the Cloud, the ISP is likely managed by your cloud provider, with OAuth / OIDC for both authz and authn -- in a nutshell it's a bit like SAML but more versatile _(allows token renewals, non-interactive authn for service accounts, mult-factor authn for humans, etc)_

Comment: Optionally the cloudy ISP may be linked to your corporate ISP and redirect one step further for authn (via OIDC or SAML); but authz is likely managed only in the cloud provider IAM system.

Comment: TL;DR >> the only truly transparent SSO that I know about is when your on-prem web app relies on SPNego which relies on your Windows session creds obtained from Active Directory (i.e. a Kerberos token renewed automatically, you only authenticate once when opening the session). Unfortunately the great user experience has security implications.

Comment: Thanks! That was super helpful and interesting. You are correct that the “auto-login” are cloud based systems. I will chat to our team on monday. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a LOT of research and testing I finally have the answer to this question, and it is incredibly simple!

In summary:
I have a working solution with OneLogin that sends me to a page like this:

```
https://sts.companyname.com/adfs/ls
```

The url is specified in the config: saml->config->idp->singleSignOnService->url

However, this page requires the user to enter their username and password and, instead, I would like the system to be fully seamless.

The solution, it turns out, is simply to hyperlink to the following url:

```
https://sts.companyname.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx?LoginToRp=https://mypage.com/saml/metadata
```

where "loginToRp" url is the url provided in saml->config->sp->entityID

The ADFS IDP Initiated Signon will connect to your metadata schema and automatically log the user in (without the user needing to provide any credentials)

NOTE: this only applies to intranet sites in a corporate environment

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of mechanisms that support an "automatic" authentication like what you describe. In the Identity and Access Management (IAM) realm, we have all sorts of names for it, but many of us call that "seamless single sign-on (SSO)".

Within a corporate environment, I would suspect that you are dealing with a one of two mechanisms: Kerberos authentication (especially if you're a Microsoft shop and log in to a domain-joined machine on a daily basis), or your machine is in an MDM-type of system, which uses a machine- and/or user-based certificate (aka PKI) to authenticate the user or user/machine combination.

Within your enterprise, if there are other applications whose users are immediately authenticated to the application without entering their username and password, then you should talk to your IAM team or your Single Sign On (SSO) administrators to understand why that doesn't work for yours.

I will also say that it's possible that your security team evaluated what information your application offers (insider financials? source code? your secret recipe? credit card data?) and decided that they would **still** require the user enter their username and password to get access to the data. So when you go to your SSO admins to ask, if they say that it's intentional, you should feel free to ask why and who you should talk to about it.

Comment: Thx. That is helpful. To add: we use Microsoft LDAP I believe. Also, the users are all on VPN, so we are logged into the company at the time of the seamless login. Let me know if that changes your answer. I will reach out to the IAM team on Monday.